# Tibble: operation on list columns

Tags: r, tibble

I have the following tibble:

```
temp <- structure(list(x = list(1:10, 1:10), y = list(c(3L, 9L, 10L, 
8L, 1L), c(1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L))), .Names = c("x", "y"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))


> temp
# A tibble: 2 x 2
           x         y
      <list>    <list>
1 <int [10]> <int [5]>
2 <int [10]> <int [5]>
```

I would like to create a new column `z` that is the setdiff of the elements of the lists in columns `x` and `y`, such that `temp$z` should output as:

```
> temp$z
[[1]]
[1] 2 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

and temp would update as:

```
> temp
# A tibble: 2 x 3
           x         y         z
      <list>    <list>    <list>
1 <int [10]> <int [5]> <int [5]>
2 <int [10]> <int [5]> <int [5]>
```

PS: A dplyr solution would be great! :-)

Comment: I'm not sure about *dplyr*, but with *purrr* you could do something like `temp$z = pmap(temp, ~setdiff(.x, .y) )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Map` in `mutate`:

```
temp %>% mutate(z=Map(setdiff, x, y))
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#            x         y         z
#       <list>    <list>    <list>
# 1 <int [10]> <int [5]> <int [5]>
# 2 <int [10]> <int [5]> <int [5]>

temp %>% mutate(z=Map(setdiff, x, y)) %>% pull(z)
# [[1]]
# [1] 2 4 5 6 7
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`purrr::map2`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) within mutate.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

temp %>% mutate(z = map2(x, y, setdiff))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>            x         y         z
#>       <list>    <list>    <list>
#> 1 <int [10]> <int [5]> <int [5]>
#> 2 <int [10]> <int [5]> <int [5]>
```

Answer (score 1):

or just base while we're at it :)

```
within(temp,z<-Map(setdiff, x, y))
```